# Powershell EMail: How to add new line in email Body?

Tags: powershell, email, newline

Very new to Powershell. Wrote powershell script which is working perfectly but when it sends mail it does not show new line character in body. Following are configurations:

```
$EmailFrom = "monitoring@mydomainname.no"
$EmailTo = "fatherazrael@tcs.com"
$Subject = "Disk Space Low: $server"

$Body = "Server Name:  $server, <NEED NEW LINE> Drive: C,  <NEED NEW LINE>  Total Size: $sizeGB,  <NEED NEW LINE> Space Left: $freeSpaceGB"

$SMTPServer = "scan.opinergo.fn"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25)
#$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("<From mail ID>", "Password");
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

In Body i have used following in place of ; searched around:

1) %0d%0a - NOT WORKING when user checks mail

2) \n - NOT WORKING when user checks mail

3) < br > - Not Working when user check mail

Could anyone please suggest what else could i use to get new line or any modifications required in script?

Comment: The PowerShell newline is `\`n` (backtick-n), have you tried that?

Comment: No. Not got that yet in searches. Thanks. Trying.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler
Thanks. It is working

Comment: Please notice that since Outlook 2003 double `\n` are removed by default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/message-body/line-breaks-are-removed-in-posts-made-in-plain-text

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(From my comment)

The PowerShell newline indicator is `n (backtick-n), so:

```
$Body = "Server Name:  $server, <NEED NEW LINE> Drive: C
```

becomes:

```
$Body = "Server Name:  $server, `n Drive: C
```

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure how these other users were able to make the `n create a new line but I never could get it to work...

Instead I ended up doing the following...

- Using the `-BodyAsHtml` switch
- Using the `<br />` (break) html tag

For example...

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer 'myemail.server.com' -To 'Mr To <to@server.com>' -From 'Mr From <from@server.com>' -Subject 'Reports From Daily SQL Backup Jobs' -Body 'There was an issue backing up the databases and sending them to the virtual drive.<br />Test Line 2.<br />Test Line 3.-more on line 3<br />Test Line 4.<br />EOF<br />'"
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried "`r", "`n", "`r`n", [System.Environment]::NewLine and a few combinations I have forgotten. I would either get no carriage return or 2 carriage returns, it was obnoxious.

Comment: Yea, I spent way to long on it as well.  It drove me nuts till I figured using html was the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

technically it needs to be

```
$body = "first line" + "`n" + "second line"
```

otherwise the the first line is created with a trailing and the second line with a leading space.

Comment: Instead of creating a new answer, comment on or edit the existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting it in your script the way you want it to appear worked for me, although I am on version 4.0.  Not sure what version you were on or if that makes a difference.

```
$Body = "Server Name:  $server
Drive: C
Total Size: $sizeGB
Space Left: $freeSpaceGB"
```

Comment: It doesn't show it above, but each piece is on it's own line

Comment: Welcome to SO! I fixed the typesetting for you. For general guidance see https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering or https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for hints about typesetting.

Answer (score -1):

The PowerShell newline indicator is `n, and can only be used in double quotes.  Single quotes will print the actual "`n".

```
$Body = "Server Name:  $server, <NEED NEW LINE> Drive: C"
```

becomes:

```
$Body = "Server Name:  $server,`nDrive: C"
```

Comment: Please don't copy paste other users' answers.